# Переместить фигуру с помощью циклов в Javascript

Tags: javascript, циклы

Прошу помощи с учебной задачей. Не прошу писать все решение, подскажите хоть как в данной задаче в JS выразить мысль (дальше разберусь):

```
Двигать квадрат вправо, пока длина не более 450px или 9 клеток
```

Думал типа этого

```
function plan(piece) do {
piece.addStep('right');  
while (top: 0; right: 450; addStep+=50px;)
 }
```

но это не оно (по кр мере ничего не происходит)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Go through the MAZE</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: gray;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
        }

        .controls {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .result {
            display: inline-block;
            color: red;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .result--success {
            color: green;
        }

        .start {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .field {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            background-color: white;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            float: left;
        }

        .field__cell {
            flex-basis: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--top {
            box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--top-right {
            box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 black, 4px 0 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--top-left {
            box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 0 black, -4px 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--right {
            box-shadow: 4px 0 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--bottom {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--bottom-right {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 black, 4px 0 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--bottom-left {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 black, -4px 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--left {
            box-shadow: -4px 0 0 black, inset 0 0 0 1px palegreen;
        }

        .field__cell--target:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: darkorange;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .piece {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .piece:after {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            background-color: darkorange;
            border-radius: 7px;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="field">
    <div class="piece" style="top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--top-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-right"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--right"></div>

    <div class="field__cell field__cell--left field__cell--target"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom"></div>
    <div class="field__cell field__cell--bottom-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="controls">
    <div>
        <button class="start">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<script>
    const defaultPiecePosition = 'top: 0; left: 0;';
    const successResult = 'success!';
    const failResult = 'fail!';
    const successModifier = 'result--success';
    const start = document.querySelector('.start');
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    const fieldElement = document.querySelector('.field');
    const cellsElements = document.querySelectorAll('.field__cell');
    const pieceElement = document.querySelector('.piece');

    class Field {
        constructor() {
            this.field = fieldElement;
            this.cells = cellsElements;
            this.opposites = {
                'up': 'down',
                'down': 'up',
                'left': 'right',
                'right': 'left'
            }
        }

        wallThere(direction, classes) {
            return classes.indexOf(direction) !== -1;
        }

        inTheSameRow(current, next) {
            return (current - current % 10) / 10 === (next - next % 10) / 10
        }

        findNextCell(currentIndex, direction) {
            let nextIndex = currentIndex;

            switch (direction) {
                case 'up':
                    nextIndex = currentIndex - 10;
                    if (nextIndex < 0) {
                        nextIndex = -1;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'right':
                    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
                    if (!this.inTheSameRow(currentIndex, nextIndex)) {
                        nextIndex = -1;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'down':
                    nextIndex = currentIndex + 10;
                    if (nextIndex > 100) {
                        nextIndex = -1;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'left':
                    nextIndex = currentIndex - 1;
                    if (!this.inTheSameRow(currentIndex, nextIndex)) {
                        nextIndex = -1;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    nextIndex = -1;
                    break;
            }

            return this.cells[nextIndex];
        }

        checkCell(currentTop, currentLeft, direction) {
            let cellIndex = (currentTop / 50 * 10 + currentLeft / 50);
            let cell = this.cells[cellIndex];
            let nextCell = this.findNextCell(cellIndex, direction);

            return !(
                this.wallThere(direction, cell.classList.toString()) ||
                typeof nextCell === 'undefined' ||
                this.wallThere(this.opposites[direction], nextCell.classList.toString())
            );
        }
    }

    class Piece {
        constructor() {
            this.piece = pieceElement;
            this.steps = [];
            this.finished = false;
            this.timeout = 400;
            this.field = new Field();
        }

        addStep(direction) {
            this.steps.push({direction})
        }

        makeNext(step, endAfterIt) {
            let top = Number(this.piece.style.top.replace('px', ''));
            let left = Number(this.piece.style.left.replace('px', ''));
            let nextLeft = left;
            let nextTop = top;

            switch (step.direction) {
                case 'left':
                    break;

                case 'down':
                    nextTop += 50;
                    break;

                case 'up':
                    break;

                case 'right':
                    nextLeft += 50;
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
            }

            if (this.finished) {
                return;
            }

            if (this.field.checkCell(top, left, step.direction)) {

                this.piece.setAttribute('style', 'top: ' + nextTop + 'px; left: ' + nextLeft + 'px;');

                if (nextTop === 450 && nextLeft === 0) {
                    this.finished = true;
                }

                if (this.finished) {
                    this.end(true);
                }
            }

            if (!this.finished && endAfterIt) {
                this.end(false);
            }
        }

        end(success) {
            if (success) {
                result.textContent = successResult;
                result.classList.add(successModifier);
            } else {
                result.textContent = failResult;
                result.classList.remove(successModifier);
            }
        }

        go() {
            this.steps.forEach((step, index) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const endAfterIt = index === this.steps.length - 1;
                    this.makeNext(step, endAfterIt);
                }, (index + 1) * this.timeout);
            });
        }
    }


    function reset() {
        pieceElement.setAttribute('style', defaultPiecePosition);
        result.textContent = '';
        result.classList.remove(successModifier);
    }

    function run() {
        let piece = new Piece();

        plan(piece);
        piece.go();
    }

    function plan(piece) {
        piece.addStep('left');
        piece.addStep('up');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('right');
        piece.addStep('down');
        piece.addStep('down');
        piece.addStep('down');
        piece.addStep('down');
    }

    function main() {
        reset();
        run();
    }

    start.addEventListener('click', main);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а что не так с предоставленным кодом?

Comment: function plan(piece) - двигает фигуру по одному шагу. А задача не написать каждый шаг отдельно,  а написать цикл, что бы фигура пришла к выходу. Я же прошу не все решение, а только строчку которую указал.

Comment: for (i=0; i<10;i++){
piece.addStep('right');
}

Comment: @Lukas спасибо, но не работает (квадрат не двигается) function plan(piece)  {
           for (i=0; i<10; i++){ piece.addStep('right'); }

Comment: https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/RYqaEx?editors=1111

Comment: @Lukas Спасибо, добрый человек! Вы лучший!